# How to Get Count() for multiple rows of same Worker in sqlserver?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, count, subquery, inner-join

i am listing `TaskList` in `GridView1` and to the right of the Listing i am Displaying the Workers List `having different skills under one`serviceCategoryID. The Display of Worker List is Filtered after Clicking on `GridView1` Row and all the `Workers with multiple skills under one serviceCategoryID are Listed in GridView2`.

Before Alloting the Task to any Worker i want to display the number of `PendingTasks` of that Worker in `GridView2` Which is `List of Workers with multiple skills under one selected serviceCategoryID from GridView1.`

Current SQL Query is:

```
SELECT WorkerMst.workerID, WorkerMst.FName, WorkerMst.LName,WorkerMst.FName +' '+ WorkerMst.LName as Name,WorkerSkills.WorkerSkillsID,
     WorkerSkills.WorkerID AS WorkerSkills_WorkerID, WorkerSkills.SkillTypeID AS WorkerSkills_SkillTypeID, WorkerSkills.Score, skillTypeMst.skillTypeID, skillTypeMst.skillType, 
     serviceCategoryMaster.serviceCategoryMasterID, serviceCategoryMaster.CategoryName, WorkerMst.IsActive AS WorkerMst_IsActive,WorkerMst.IsIndividual,WorkerMst.readyfornewtask,
     (select count(WorkerID)from WorkerTask where isAproved=0 and workerid in (select distinct(workerid) from workertask where isaproved=0 group by workerid)) as PendingTsks

 FROM WorkerMst 
 INNER JOIN WorkerSkills ON WorkerMst.workerID = WorkerSkills.WorkerID 
 INNER JOIN skillTypeMst ON WorkerSkills.SkillTypeID = skillTypeMst.skillTypeID 
 INNER JOIN serviceCategoryMaster ON skillTypeMst.serviceCategoryMasterID = serviceCategoryMaster.serviceCategoryMasterID
where skillTypeMst.serviceCategoryMasterID=1 and 
WorkerMst.workerID in (select distinct(workerid) from workertask where isaproved=0)
order by workermst.workerid
```

[image]

`WorkerTask` Table has Following Fields:

```
WorkerID,TaskMstID,IsAccepted ,IsRejected,OnDate,isAproved
```

Any Suggestion?
Help Appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided schema of your tables but I am assuming that the `WorkerTask` table would have one row for a task assignment to (any) worker. I am assuming that `WorkerTaskId` is primary key of this table then following query should suffice:

```
SELECT 
     WorkerMst.workerID, WorkerMst.FName, WorkerMst.LName,
     WorkerMst.FName +' '+ WorkerMst.LName as Name,WorkerSkills.WorkerSkillsID,
     WorkerSkills.WorkerID AS WorkerSkills_WorkerID, 
     WorkerSkills.SkillTypeID AS WorkerSkills_SkillTypeID, WorkerSkills.Score,
     skillTypeMst.skillTypeID, skillTypeMst.skillType, 
     serviceCategoryMaster.serviceCategoryMasterID, serviceCategoryMaster.CategoryName, 
      WorkerMst.IsActive AS WorkerMst_IsActive, WorkerMst.IsIndividual, 
      WorkerMst.readyfornewtask,
     (select count(t.workertaskid)from WorkerTask t
         where t.isAproved=0 and t.workerid = WorkerMst.workerid) as PendingTsks
 FROM WorkerMst 
 INNER JOIN WorkerSkills ON WorkerMst.workerID = WorkerSkills.WorkerID 
 INNER JOIN skillTypeMst ON WorkerSkills.SkillTypeID = skillTypeMst.skillTypeID 
 INNER JOIN serviceCategoryMaster 
    ON skillTypeMst.serviceCategoryMasterID =  serviceCategoryMaster.serviceCategoryMasterID
where skillTypeMst.serviceCategoryMasterID=1 
order by workermst.workerid
```

Comment: hello @VinayC thanks for showing interest in trying to solve my query but, unfortunately their is ERROR since u have used Clause "in=WorkerMSt.workerId" in query..plz check..!I have edited my code with table structure that u need..!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE, `in` shouldn't be there. Also remember my assumption that WorkerTaskId being primary key - so adjust the query accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @VinayC after modifying above query i got the result that i need...! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Modifed Query:

```
SELECT 
     WorkerMst.workerID, WorkerMst.FName, WorkerMst.LName,
     WorkerMst.FName +' '+ WorkerMst.LName as Name,WorkerSkills.WorkerSkillsID,
     WorkerSkills.WorkerID AS WorkerSkills_WorkerID, 
     WorkerSkills.SkillTypeID AS WorkerSkills_SkillTypeID, WorkerSkills.Score,
     skillTypeMst.skillTypeID, skillTypeMst.skillType, 
     serviceCategoryMaster.serviceCategoryMasterID, serviceCategoryMaster.CategoryName, 
      WorkerMst.IsActive AS WorkerMst_IsActive, WorkerMst.IsIndividual, 
      WorkerMst.readyfornewtask,(select count(workerid)from WorkerTask 
         where isAproved=0 and workerid = WorkerMst.workerid) as PendingTsks

 FROM WorkerMst 
 INNER JOIN WorkerSkills ON WorkerMst.workerID = WorkerSkills.WorkerID 
 INNER JOIN skillTypeMst ON WorkerSkills.SkillTypeID = skillTypeMst.skillTypeID 
 INNER JOIN serviceCategoryMaster 
    ON skillTypeMst.serviceCategoryMasterID =  serviceCategoryMaster.serviceCategoryMasterID
where skillTypeMst.serviceCategoryMasterID=1 and WorkerSkills.Score>=70
order by workermst.workerid
```

Thanks @VinayC for your suggestion!